# Series of conditional table and cell references

Tags: vba, excel

I have a reference table as such in Sheet2 of my workbook

```
         |Score 1|     |        |Score 2 |      |        |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  name  |  min  | max | target |  min   | max  | target |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  jeff  | 30    | 40  |  35    |  45    |  55  |  50    |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  steve | 35    | 45  |  40    |  45    |  65  |  55    |
```

then in Sheet1 I have a list of scores for each name as such

```
| jeff | 1 |      |      |       | steve | 3  |      |     |
------------------------------------------------------------
| jeff | 2 |      |      |       | steve | 2  |      |     |
------------------------------------------------------------
| jeff | 2 |      |      |       | steve | 3  |      |     |
------------------------------------------------------------
| jeff | 3 |      |      |       | steve | 3  |      |     |
------------------------------------------------------------
| jeff | 1 |      |      |       | steve | 2  |      |     |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am aware of simple lookups and offsetting values but I can't think of a way to do multiple references on different levels... Is there a way to in Sheet1 next to the scores have a function that looks up the score, then who the score is for, and then prints the corresponding min max and target values for that person with that score.

So if it sees 1 and then jeff, it returns 30 | 40 | 35 in the next 3 boxes. I would do this manually but the list is very long and is populated daily by an existing macro.

Comment: Users asking for code or formulas are **expected** to show what they have come up with to resolve the problem themselves (working or not). [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) is **not** your free, personal code-writing service.

Comment: Jeeped, I appreciate the intention of SO hence nowhere in my question have I asked someone to provide a solution of which I can copy and paste. I HAVE asked if there is a way of doing it. I mention my understanding of individual lookups but i know nothing on how to construct conditional lookups in VBA! A simple point in the right direction would go a long way and that is all I am asking for. e.g a maths student with a calculator wants to add up all numbers. Teacher doesn't take the calculator and do it for him but he does point him to the summation button and explains what it does! :@

Comment: Fair enough. Format Sheet2!1:1 as `[Color13]\Sco\r\e 0` then type in 1, 2, 3, etc into the first column of each score section. Now in Sheet1 you can use [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) as a [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) to locate the first score. The same down column A locates the name. The rest is simple addition.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped, appreciate the tips, i'll look into this way and let you know how it turns out

Answer (score 0):

Use VLOOKUP with the name (jeff) and take the index (1) to calculate the column to take.